# largest positive root

Tags: polynomials, radicals

Let$\;\,r=a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c},\;\,$where

- $a,b,c\;$are rational numbers, with $b,c > 0$.

  Each of$\;\,b\,,c,\,bc\;\;$is not the square of a rational number.

  $r > 0$.

Let $f(x)$ be the minimal monic polynomial with rational coefficients for which $r$ is a root.

Based on data from numerical examples, the following claim appears to be true:

- If $f$ has more than one positive root, then $r$ is the largest of them.

Is it true?

Comment: "$f$ has more than `?` positive root"

Comment: Hint: What are the conjugates of $r$?

Comment: @Jaideep Khare: Oh, I see I left out the "one" (now edited).. Thanks.

Comment: @ccorn: Got it! Thanks. I was looking at the numerical values (in decimal), when I should have been thinking about the algebraic forms for the other $3$ roots.

Comment: Moreover, the condition $r>0$ isn't needed -- $r$ wlll always be the largest root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square both sides twice.

$(x-a)^2=b+c+2\sqrt{bc} $

$\big((x-a)^2-b-c\big)^2=4bc $

Then
$x=a+\sqrt b-\sqrt c$,
$x=a-\sqrt b+\sqrt c$,
$x=a-\sqrt b-\sqrt c$
are solutions, $r$ is maximum.